# 1px undesignated border between vertical divs in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

There's a lot of code here, and I'm not sure what's causing it. The site in question is www.wearedeja.com

When viewing the page in Chrome there is a 1px border between each row of divs on top of each other -  notice that the mouse will flash from the index finger(designating a clickable link) to the arrow when moving the mouse vertically, and if you try hard enough you can hover your mouse right between the divs. This doesn't happen horizontally. I don't want a single pixel on this site not clickable, and I've tried everything I can think of to remove it. In Firefox this doesn't happen at all(I know the text is messed up in FF.. working on that too)

On a select few spaces this doesn't happen. This should lead to reproducible results but I can't seem to figure it out. I believe it's either something to do with the lowest level divs or the text...

Here's the relevant code

**HTML STRUCTURE**

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="row">
        <div class="cell"><div id="text"></div></div>
        <div class="cell"><div id="text"></div></div>
        <div class="cell"><div id="text"></div></div>
        <div class="cell"><div id="text"></div></div>
        </div>
    <div id="row">
        <div class="cell"><div id="text"></div></div>
        <div class="cell"><div id="text"></div></div>
        <div class="cell"><div id="text"></div></div>   
        <div class="cell"><div id="text"></div></div>
        </div>
    <div id="row">
        <div class="cell"><div id="text"></div></div>
        <div class="cell"><div id="text"></div></div>
        <div class="cell"><div id="text"></div></div>
        <div class="cell"><div id="text"></div></div>
        </div>
    <div id="row">
        <div class="cell"><div id="text"></div></div>
        <div class="cell"><div id="text"></div></div>
        <div class="cell"><div id="text"></div></div>
        <div class="cell"><div id="text"></div></div>
        </div>
        </div>
```

**CSS**

```
    #text{
    opacity:1;
    display:table;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:999;
    color:#fff;
    text-align:center;
    width:100%;
    top:44%;
    left:0;
    }

/* table rules */
    .container{
    display:table-row;
    width:100%;
    }

    .row{
    display:table-row;
    width:100%;
    }

    .cell{
    vertical-align: top;
    position:relative;
    display:table-cell;
    background-color:black;
    width:700px;
    height:auto;
    }

    body{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    }

        /* image rules */
    img{
    max-height:600px;
    max-width:600px;
    height:auto;
    width:100%;
    }
```

If you know what's causing this, please try to explain why this doesn't happen in FF so I can avoid it in the future... Thanks

Comment: hmm interesting, you have `id="container"` but you use `.container` in your CSS... same for `.row` etc. please give us a code that **reproduces the issue**.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I believe OP did give his code - that's what's on the website. So, that'd first thing to fix, fuccboi - correct the `id` and `class` mix-matches. Also, consider moving your CSS to an external file for usability and organization and web standards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your images are not showing up as the same dimension so the background is showing through... The black lines change and disappear based on the browser window size (an odd size divided by 4 can't have 4 evenly sized images).

I would try using the images as background images so that you can more precisely position them with the `background-size` property.

Like this:

#### HTML (add classes to `.cell`)

```
<div class="cell A1">...</div>
<div class="cell D1">...</div>
```

#### Additional CSS

```
.A1 {
    background: url(A1.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
}

.D1 {
    background: url(D1.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
}
```

You will probably have to play around with your `<a>` tag width and height and `.cell` height, though. The easiest and quickest way would be to use somewhat of a *hack*, like replace the current `<img>`s with a transparent gif to keep the cells and links sizing the way the currently do, and then the **background images** in there for the visual.

Also, if you use more than one of something, shouldn't it be a **class** and not an **id**?

Comment: I see what you're getting at, thanks for the tips too. So maybe class each lowest level(the ones only holding the images) all separately and then background-image:"asdf.jpg"?

Comment: add class to each cell and then in CSS use something like `.spindrift { background-image: url(A1.jpg); background-size: cover; }`

Answer (score 1):

It's not a border, it's the `background-color` of `.cell` showing through. Because they are set to `display: table-cell;` the height will be that of the tallest cell in the row. However, some of your images are 313px wide and 312px tall and some are 313px wide and 313px tall. This means that while some images within those cells are covering the entire 313px high, some of your images are 1px shy, thus showing the background of the parent container.

If you fix up your images, everything will right itself. How do I know that? Because if you force a height of **all** images, the black lines all go away:

```
img { height: 312px; }
```

:)

Comment: The images are actually all 420x420; i'm using a fluid layout with lots of percentages. I want the images to stretch from each sides of the screen no matter the screen size. Now that you've pointed this out, I think the reason this might be happening in chrome and not firefox has something to do with the way they resize images... that being said, know of any workarounds?

Comment: Ahh, a fluid layout, yes this is a problem, because if the width/height sits in between two whole pixels, it rounds, and you get funny results. You would probably be better off having a `background-image` on `.cell a` and also have the anchor stretch to fit the entire `.cell`. The `background-size` could be set to `cover` to fit into the dimensions of `.cell` and shouldn't be affected negatively by changing window size.